# Typescript: Make Interface Property Required

Tags: typescript

I apologize if this is something simple, I'm new to Typescript.

Given the following code:

```
interface Test {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string;
}

init({ 
  prop1: "yep", 
  prop3: "nope" 
});

function init(arg1: any) {
  return doStuff(arg1);
}

function doStuff(arg1: Test) {
  console.log("arg1", arg1);
}
```

I was hoping this would throw an error when "init" attempts to call "doStuff" with an inappropriately structured object.

It currently prints

```
arg1 { prop1: 'yep', prop3: 'nope' }
```

How do I make it required that prop2 exists?

Comment: You specified `init` to take `arg1: any`. Why not `Test`? You are telling the compiler to ignore the type check.

Comment: Good question, in real life, this object is coming in as a POST body, so when it reaches the code I'm trying to make, it's in this "any" structure. I want to throw an error. I was trying to avoid having to check for each property manually, and then throwing. Perhaps this is the only way?

Comment: the "any" keyword means that this argument is assumed to fill any interface, in a way, you're telling typescript to shut up bc you know what you're doing. You need to type the http response correctly to make this work.

Comment: The type-safety that typescript gives you happens at transpile time, not at runtime. It has no idea what your post data looks like.

Comment: Gotcha, I don't know what the body looks either (it could be anything), and I wanted to make sure that it throws an error when a required property is missing. I can check manually, I thought that it would be something supported by defining an interface. Perhaps not, Thank you for the responses!

Comment: It is not supported, interfaces are for helping you as a developer write code by providing typings.  You do need to write functions to explicitly check the type and typescript provides special function syntax for doing this.

Comment: Understood, appreciate the comment. I'm not sure if it would make sense to delete this question now, or not.

Comment: I think it's a good question.  It's calling out the difference between static compile time checks vs. runtime checks. In you case, you want a runtime check since it's arbitrary data coming from http.

Comment: You can use some runtime assertion libraries for that.

Comment: I think I am just going to use manual checks, to make sure all required properties exist. If someone would like to add an answer, I will gladly accept it, thank you for your responses.